# The right procedure to upgrade RDS Postgres instance with read replica?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

The current version is 9.4.20 and I want to upgrade to 9.5.X. I am wondering the right procedure to do this since my Postgres has read replica so it is a bit more than just `Modify`. `Downtime` is acceptable. The seamless upgrade is *NOT* required. The docs on the AWS side are not clear. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlCqV.png

[amz docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html)

Here are the purposed steps, yet I can't figure out how to perform the second step:

1. take a snapshot of the primary instance,
2. stop replication,
3. upgrade a primary instance,
4. upgrade read replica,
5. promote read replica and start replication again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will just post what I did as an answer.

1. snapshot primary,
2. delete old read replica,
3. upgrade primary,
4. create new read replica, done.

Answer (score 3):

The RDS for PostgreSQL doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html states:
"A read replica can't undergo a major version upgrade but the read replica's source instance can. If a read replica's source instance undergoes a major version upgrade, all read replicas for that source instance remain with the previous engine version. In this case, the read replicas can no longer replicate changes performed on the source instance.

We recommend that you either promote your read replicas, or delete and recreate them after the source instance has upgraded to a different major version."

When you initiate a major version upgrade for an RDS for PostgreSQL instance with one or more read replicas, the replication will be automatically stopped, and it won't be restarted after the primary (source) is finished upgrading. You will need to create new read replicas after upgrading the source database instance.